# How do I create an element with multiple background images coming from multiple CSS classes?

Tags: html, css, background-image

CSS allows an element to have multiple background images via `background-image: url("first.png"), url("second.png"), url("third.png")`

```
header {
  background-image: url("header.png");
}

.with-foo {
  background-image: url("with-foo.png");
}

.with-bar {
  background-image: url("with-bar.png");
}

.with-foobar {
  background-image: url("with-foobar.png");
}
```

```html
<header class="with-foo with-bar with-foobar">
  ...
</header>
```

In the above code, the header will have the background image `with-foobar.png` because the style overwrites the other previous statements.

Is it possible to **add** images to the `background-image` property using CSS only or would I have to go with a JavaScript solution?

Comment: How exactly do you want the multiple backgrounds to look like?

Comment: Of course the images would have to use transparency so they stack up, otherwise only the last image would be visible.

Comment: Right, that uses multiple images in one selector which is what I wrote in my first sentence. What I wanted to achieve is layer the image using multiple selectors (CSS classes). Thought this might be possible.

Comment: I guess  if they are transparent and stacking, you could just create separate elements and stack them (eg `<header class="with-foo"><div class="with-bar">...`) if you are not wanting to combine the images into one class

Answer (score -1):

No, because even if you could, how would you specify which images should be placed higher and which lower? You wouldn't be able to do this by rearranging the class names, because the class attribute doesn't have a notion of order (and even if it did, the cascade is still your enemy here, as you've demonstrated).

Since there is no other way of specifying which images should be placed higher or lower other than within a single `background-image` declaration, you are forced to write that declaration — and the accompanying selector — in full.

The alternative is to have a dedicated element for each class name and each background image, but unless you don't care about semantics (which, judging by your use of `header`, is probably not the case), that's a *terrible* option.

Comment: Oh, I understand, didn't know that.